# android unit test coverage to one single line

Tags: android, unit-testing, sonarqube

Say below code, I want to cover code line `x = x*2`.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class A {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    int x = 1;
    int limits = 5 * 60;
    private B b = new B();
    public A() {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    private void run() {
        executor.schedule(new MyRunnable(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean status = b.getStatus();
            if (!status) {
                if (x < limits) {
                    x = x * 2; // coverage line
                }
                int delay = Math.min(x, limits);
                executor.schedule(new MyRunnable(), delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }else{
                //doSomething
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try below code but sonarqube test still fail.

```
@Test
public void case1() throws Exception {
    int duration = 4*60;
    A aobj = new A();
    A amock = PowerMockito.spy(aobj);

    B bmock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
    Mockito.when(bmock.getStatus()).thenReturn(false);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(amock, "x", duration);
    Whitebox.invokeMethod(amock,"run");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    int t = Whitebox.getInternalState(amock, "x");
    assertEquals(t,duration*2);
}
```

Questions:

1. Currently I try to mock code run into the `x = x*2` code line one time, then wait sometime to check if the x value has been doubled. Is this right logic to get the line covered?

2.. How can remove the Thread.sleep() logic since sonarqube give a warning.